# cumulative integral with respect to centered function

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, derivatives

I have a symmetric discrete function f(k) where k is monotonic and evenly spaced. If I compute the cumulative integral of the derivative of the signal, then the original signal is regenerated, as expected (figure 1). If I scale each value of the derivative by displacement from the center of k and then compute the integral it yields a value equal to -2N * the integral of f(k), where N is the number of elements in k. Why is this so (analytically)? Also, why does the cumulative integral of the centered derivative have smooth curves (figure 2)?

Thank you.

[image: figure 1]
[image: figure 2]

The matlab code producing these figures is below:

```
H = 1;
k = -120:H:120;
N = numel(k);
fk = [linspace(0,120,121) linspace(119,0,120)];
dfk1 = gradient(fk,k);
dfk2 = k.*gradient(fk,k);
idfk1 = fk(1)+cumtrapz(dfk1);
idfk2 = fk(1)+cumtrapz(dfk2);

sum(fk)
sum(idfk1)
sum(idfk2) * -2/N

figure(1);clf;
subplot(1,3,1)
plot(k,fk)
title('f(k)')
subplot(1,3,2)
plot(k,dfk1)
title('df/dk')
subplot(1,3,3)
plot(k,idfk1)
title('cumtrapz(df/dk)')

figure(2);clf;
subplot(1,3,1)
plot(k,fk)
title('f(k)')
subplot(1,3,2)
plot(k,dfk2)
title('df/dk, centered')
subplot(1,3,3)
plot(k,idfk2)
title('cumtrapz(df/dk, centered)')
```